# How to count the number of instances of a Class in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Java, we can use the `instance initialization block` to keep track of count of any class objects.

So, in dart how can we do that for a class with `const Constructor`?

I know that for a non-constant  Constructor, we can achieve that by creating a `static variable` then incrementing its value in Constructor body.

But as we know that, `const Constructor` can't have a body, then how to keep track of number of instances created for a particular class ?

Comment: You can use the [memory view](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory) in [dart devtools](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools) to see [number of instances of a class](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory#allocation-view).

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one instance of a class made with a `const` constructor. The one instance is instantiated during compilation, and all `const` calls to the constructor return it.

If you want to count the number of times a `const` constructor is used in a non-`const` context, this is not possible, because code with the potential to be executed during compilation cannot cause runtime side-effects.

Consider using a factory constructor for this purpose, like so:

```dart
class MyClass {
  static var _instances = 0;

  const MyClass();

  factory MyClass.tracked() {
    ++_instances;
    return const MyClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can have many `const` instances of a class so long as you pass different arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can a (generative, non-redirecting) `const` constructor not have a body, it also cannot run *any* code with a side-effect. That's by design, so there is no way around it.

There really is no way, inside the language and program, to count instances of that class.

Using the developer tools is the only viable approach, because it can scan the actual runtime memory and see how many instances exist.